# Running sql scripts with interdependencies

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I have a project utilizing a postgres database in the backend and I'm working to create a Dockerfile which can automatically set up a local development instance of the db. The database includes a large number of functions, and these have historically been stored in context-appropriate sql files e.g. users.sql, companies.sql. This has been fine as whenever changes are made, I can simply execute the relevant sql files which `REPLACE` all Views and drop/recreate all of the Functions.

However, when trying to run these scripts on a fresh postgres instance (after `CREATE`ing all tables), they fail because most of the views/functions reference other views functions which are not defined yet.

I have begun investigating if there is a particular order I can run the scripts in to avoid this issue, but since they weren't designed with this purpose in mind it may be impossible, and there is a large number of entities at play so this is most likely a non-trivial task.

Is there any way to achieve this apart from restructuring the scripts?

Comment: I believe restructuring your scripts and the order in which you apply them is the right (and only) way to go here. Perhaps you can get creative by scraping through the scripts looking for dependencies to reorder, but it would probably be faster to just go by hand since this is a one-time thing. Perhaps as a stop-gap you can just rerun the scripts over and over and over again until all objects are created, ignoring errors until all the errors disappear... :(

Comment: I figured that was likely the case, thanks for your help!

Comment: A pg_dump -Cs DB > db.sql of the "working" database should give you pretty good idea how to restructure the create statements.

Comment: That does provide an easier solution, but doesn't allow us to keep modular sql files the way we have been for reference. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write a simple recursive query that starts with all views that don't depend on others and recursively adds the views that depend on these. Then output the view definition for these views in the correct order, and you have got your script:

```
WITH RECURSIVE viewids AS (
   /* all views that don't depend on other views */
   SELECT t.oid, 1 as level
   FROM pg_class t
      JOIN pg_rewrite AS r ON r.ev_class = t.oid
   WHERE r.rulename = '_RETURN'
     AND t.relkind = 'v'
     AND t.relnamespace NOT IN ('pg_catalog'::regnamespace,
                                'information_schema'::regnamespace,
                                'pg_toast'::regnamespace)
     AND NOT EXISTS (
            /* depends on a view */
            SELECT 1
            FROM pg_depend AS d
               JOIN pg_class AS t2 ON d.refobjid = t2.oid
            WHERE d.objid = r.oid
              AND d.classid = 'pg_rewrite'::regclass
              AND d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass
              AND d.deptype = 'n'
              AND d.refobjsubid <> 0
              AND t2.relkind = 'v'
         )
     AND NOT EXISTS (
            /* depends on an extension */
            SELECT 1
            FROM pg_depend
            WHERE objid = t.oid
              AND classid = 'pg_class'::regclass
              AND refclassid = 'pg_extension'::regclass
              AND deptype = 'e'
         )
UNION ALL
   /* all views that depend on these views */
   SELECT t.oid, viewids.level + 1
   FROM pg_class AS t
      JOIN pg_rewrite AS r ON r.ev_class = t.oid
      JOIN pg_depend AS d ON d.objid = r.oid
      JOIN viewids ON viewids.oid = d.refobjid
   WHERE t.relkind = 'v'
     AND r.rulename = '_RETURN'
     AND d.classid = 'pg_rewrite'::regclass                            
     AND d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass
     AND d.deptype = 'n'
     AND d.refobjsubid <> 0
)
/* order the views by level, eliminating duplicates */
SELECT format('CREATE VIEW %s AS%s',
              oid::regclass,
              pg_get_viewdef(oid::regclass))
FROM viewids
GROUP BY oid
ORDER BY max(level);
```

Comment: How could one include materialized views in this query? And why are materialized views handled differently? For example phpPgAdmin does not list materialized views, but views. Thanks

Comment: pgpPgAdmin may not know about materialized views. To include them, you must include `pg_class` entries with `relkind = 'm'`.

Comment: Instead of `UNION ALL` u need `UNION` because of infinite recursive

Comment: @EugeneChernyavsky If there were an infinite recursion, `UNION` wouldn't help, because the `level` is different.

Answer (score 0):

## Index support

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE viewids AS (
   /* all views that don't depend on other views */
   SELECT t.oid, 1 as level
   FROM pg_class t
      JOIN pg_rewrite AS r ON r.ev_class = t.oid
   WHERE r.rulename = '_RETURN'
     AND t.relkind in ('v', 'm')
     AND t.relnamespace NOT IN ('pg_catalog'::regnamespace,
                                'information_schema'::regnamespace,
                                'pg_toast'::regnamespace)
     AND NOT EXISTS (
            /* depends on a view */
            SELECT 1
            FROM pg_depend AS d
               JOIN pg_class AS t2 ON d.refobjid = t2.oid
            WHERE d.objid = r.oid
              AND d.classid = 'pg_rewrite'::regclass
              AND d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass
              AND d.deptype = 'n'
              AND d.refobjsubid <> 0
              AND t2.relkind in ('v', 'm')
         )
     AND NOT EXISTS (
            /* depends on an extension */
            SELECT 1
            FROM pg_depend
            WHERE objid = t.oid
              AND classid = 'pg_class'::regclass
              AND refclassid = 'pg_extension'::regclass
              AND deptype = 'e'
         )
UNION
   /* all views that depend on these views */
   SELECT t.oid, viewids.level + 1
   FROM pg_class AS t
      JOIN pg_rewrite AS r ON r.ev_class = t.oid
      JOIN pg_depend AS d ON d.objid = r.oid
      JOIN viewids ON viewids.oid = d.refobjid
   WHERE t.relkind IN ('v','m')
     AND r.rulename = '_RETURN'
     AND d.classid = 'pg_rewrite'::regclass
     AND d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass
     AND d.deptype = 'n'
     AND d.refobjsubid <> 0
), max_levels as (
    select oid, max(level) as level
    from viewids
    group by oid
), views_q as (
    SELECT
        oid,
        level,
        format('CREATE %s %s AS%s',
                CASE WHEN t.relkind = 'm' THEN 'MATERIALIZED VIEW'
                     ELSE 'VIEW'
                END,
                oid::regclass,
                pg_get_viewdef(oid::regclass))
    FROM max_levels
    INNER JOIN pg_class t USING(oid)
    ORDER BY level, oid
), index_q as (
    select distinct on (objid)
        objid as oid,
        level + 0.5 as level,
        pg_get_indexdef(objid) as indexdef
    from pg_depend
    inner join max_levels on refobjid = oid
    where deptype = 'a'
    order by objid
)
SELECT * FROM index_q
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM views_q
ORDER BY level, oid;
```

## Select dependancies by table name

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE viewids AS (
   SELECT 'foo.bar'::regclass::oid, 1 as level
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.oid, viewids.level + 1
   FROM pg_class AS t
      JOIN pg_rewrite AS r ON r.ev_class = t.oid
      JOIN pg_depend AS d ON d.objid = r.oid
      JOIN viewids ON viewids.oid = d.refobjid
   WHERE t.relkind IN ('v','m')
     AND r.rulename = '_RETURN'
     AND d.classid = 'pg_rewrite'::regclass
     AND d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass
     AND d.deptype = 'n'
     AND d.refobjsubid <> 0
), max_levels as (
    select oid, max(level) as level
    from viewids
    group by oid
), views_q as (
    SELECT
        oid,
        level,
        format('CREATE %s %s AS%s',
                CASE WHEN t.relkind = 'm' THEN 'MATERIALIZED VIEW'
                     ELSE 'VIEW'
                END,
                oid::regclass,
                pg_get_viewdef(oid::regclass))
    FROM max_levels
    INNER JOIN pg_class t USING(oid)
    ORDER BY level, oid
), index_q as (
    select distinct on (objid)
        objid as oid,
        level + 0.5 as level,
        pg_get_indexdef(objid) as indexdef
    from pg_depend
    inner join max_levels on refobjid = oid
    where deptype = 'a'
    order by objid
)
SELECT * FROM index_q WHERE level >= 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM views_q WHERE level >= 2
ORDER BY level, oid
```