# ERROR: cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule DETAIL: rule _RETURN on view depends on column "status"

Tags: postgresql, view, dependencies, sqldatatypes

I am trying to update a column of type integer to numeric(2) in postgres

```
ALTER TABLE employee_status
    ALTER COLUMN status TYPE numeric(2);
```

but getting the error
ERROR:  cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule
DETAIL:  rule _RETURN on view v_employee_details depends on column "status"

Without dropping or deleting data, how can i achieve this? is there any way to disable the rule or the view

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The only possible way is to drop and re-create the view.

But that is no problem, you can easily get the view definition with the [`pg_get_viewdef` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-info.html).

If you have a lot of dependent views, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57064393/6464308) to get all dependent views in the correct order.

Don't worry about the `_RETURN` rule: that is just an implementation detail of how views are implemented in PostgreSQL: as `ON SELECT DO INSTEAD` rule named `_RETURN`.

---

```
do $$            
  declare v_employee_details_def text;
  declare exec_text text;
begin          
  v_employee_details_def := pg_get_viewdef('v_employee_details');
  drop view v_employee_details;
  
  -- do your other stuff
  
  exec_text := format('create view v_employee_details as %s', 
      v_employee_details_def);
  execute exec_text;
end $$;
```

Comment: if i drop the view and then alter the column, it should work? What about the rule _RETURN? will the rule be deleted and re created?

Comment: I have added information about `_RETURN`. If the view definition will function with the modified table, you should be able to re-create the view afterwards.

Comment: In my case, Even after deleting the view, the problem persists, is there any other place I need to delete something?

Comment: @TalesMGodois Well, you need to drop *all* the views that depend on the column you want to modify.

Comment: So, I finally solved.  I had dropped the views but that didnt work, prisma kept thinking that the view exists.

What I did was basically rever the all migration manually, everything that prisma said that was drifiting, I reverted manually

Then,  I deleted the migration folder and re-run prisma migration dev, then it worked.

Comment: Thank you @LaurenzAlbe for this. Dropping the view, executing the schema update and re-creating the view worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I found one more solution more simple, but may be not a best practice.

`UPDATE pg_attribute SET atttypmod = 35+4  WHERE attrelid = 'TABLE1'::regclass   AND attname = 'COL1';`

You need a SUPERUSER access or similar to change Postgres system table - pg_attribute.
Here's explanation [link](https://sniptools.com/databases/resize-a-column-in-a-postgresql-table-without-changing-data/)!

Answer (score 2):

there is my full sql query based on @LaurenzAlbe's answer:

```
do $$            
  declare view_record record;
begin          

  drop table if exists public.__temp_views;

  --at first create temporary table with all view definitions
  create table public.__temp_views(schemaname text, viewname text, definition text, level float);

  --then insert recursive views with levels
  insert into public.__temp_views(schemaname, viewname, definition, level)

  WITH RECURSIVE viewids AS (
   /* all views that don't depend on other views */
   SELECT t.oid, 1 as level
   FROM pg_class t
      JOIN pg_rewrite AS r ON r.ev_class = t.oid
   WHERE r.rulename = '_RETURN'
     AND t.relkind = 'v'
     AND t.relnamespace NOT IN ('pg_catalog'::regnamespace,
                                'information_schema'::regnamespace,
                                'pg_toast'::regnamespace)
     AND NOT EXISTS (
            /* depends on a view */
            SELECT 1
            FROM pg_depend AS d
               JOIN pg_class AS t2 ON d.refobjid = t2.oid
            WHERE d.objid = r.oid
              AND d.classid = 'pg_rewrite'::regclass
              AND d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass
              AND d.deptype = 'n'
              AND d.refobjsubid <> 0
              AND t2.relkind = 'v'
         )
     AND NOT EXISTS (
            /* depends on an extension */
            SELECT 1
            FROM pg_depend
            WHERE objid = t.oid
              AND classid = 'pg_class'::regclass
              AND refclassid = 'pg_extension'::regclass
              AND deptype = 'e'
         )
  UNION ALL
    /* all views that depend on these views */
    SELECT t.oid, viewids.level + 1
    FROM pg_class AS t
        JOIN pg_rewrite AS r ON r.ev_class = t.oid
        JOIN pg_depend AS d ON d.objid = r.oid
        JOIN viewids ON viewids.oid = d.refobjid
    WHERE t.relkind = 'v'
      AND r.rulename = '_RETURN'
      AND d.classid = 'pg_rewrite'::regclass                            
      AND d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass
      AND d.deptype = 'n'
      AND d.refobjsubid <> 0
  )
  /* order the views by level, eliminating duplicates */
  SELECT 'public', oid::regclass, pg_get_viewdef(oid::regclass), max(level)
  FROM viewids
  GROUP BY oid
  ORDER BY max(level);

  --then drop all views
  FOR view_record IN SELECT * from public.__temp_views
  LOOP
    execute format('DROP VIEW IF EXISTS %s.%s CASCADE;', quote_ident(view_record.schemaname), quote_ident(view_record.viewname));
  END LOOP;

  -- then do your other stuff here
  -- for example i'm changing column that depending by views
  alter table public.connected_accounts 
  alter column provider TYPE text;

  ALTER TABLE public.connected_accounts
  ADD CONSTRAINT auth_providers_id_key
  FOREIGN KEY (provider)
  REFERENCES public.auth_providers (id) not valid;

  --then recreate all the views recursively
  FOR view_record IN SELECT * from public.__temp_views
  LOOP
    execute format('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW %s.%s AS %s;', quote_ident(view_record.schemaname), quote_ident(view_record.viewname), view_record.definition);
  END LOOP;

  --finally drop temporary table
  drop table public.__temp_views;

end $$;
```

Hope it helps someone. For me it was a life saving, because i have a lot of views that depend on each other. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @saike, you save my life with this magic script

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a way to avoid delete/drop because I thought there should be an easier way. But no, there isn't a way to avoid drop/delete. However, drop/delete and recreate is easy via UI (pgAdmin 4):

1. Right click on the specific View -> Properties

[image]

2. Copy out the Code for the View

[image]

3. Backup your DB (just in case)
4. Right click on the specific View again and choose "Delete/Drop"
5. Create new View and input that Code you've copied out earlier. Done.